# How to execute multiple bash commands in parallel in python

Tags: python

So, I have a code which takes in input and starts a spark job in cluster.. So, something like

```
spark-submit driver.py -i input_path
```

Now, I have list of paths and I want to execute all these simulatenously..

Here is what I tried

```
base_command = 'spark-submit driver.py -i %s'
for path in paths:
   command = base_command%path
    subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

My hope was, all of the shell commands would be executed simultaneously but instead, I am noticing that it executes one command at a time..

How do i execute all the bash commands simultaneously.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to be able to tell when they are all finished?

Comment: @Labo: naah.. just execute them all in parallel..

Comment: What makes you think they are not executed in parallel?

Comment: @Labo: as a test i had this
    base_command = 'spark-submit driver.py -i example.txt'
    subprocess.Popen(base_command, shell=True)
    print " i am here" 

I was hoping that it would print "i am here" but it didnt.. instead.. i was seeing all the spark log dump..

Comment: Try with for i in range(3): subprocess.Popen("sleep 4; echo 2", shell=True) and you will see that the 3 '2' are displayed at the same time.

Comment: @Labo: ah so.. basically, multiple bash commands should be executed in one string ? as one big command..

Comment: No! My example means that subprocess.Popen launch all commands approximately at the same time and is not blocking.

Comment: Try a simpler example, and you'll see that the commands are executed. Are you sure you did not miss the "i am here"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is where pool comes in, it is designed for just this case. It maps many inputs to many threads automatically. [Here](http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/) is a good resource on how to use it.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def run_command(path):
    command = "spark-submit driver.py -i {}".format(path)
    subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)

pool = Pool()
pool.map(run_command, paths)
```

It will create a thread for every item in paths and, run them all at the same time for the given input